# Single E5-1600v2 on Dual Socket motherboad

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, supermicro

Is it possible to install one E5-1650 v2 on each node on twin 1U, dual socket supermicro 1027TR-TF server?

I know that E5-1600 series cannot run in dual socket configuration. The question is that will it run if I put only one on a dual socket motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible, needs an E5-26xx v2 series CPU sorry.

(see specs [HERE](http://www.supermicro.co.uk/products/system/1U/1027/SYS-1027TR-TF.cfm))

Comment: Geez... only one power supply.

Comment: I understand that the spec only mention E5-26XX if we want to use it as dual socket motherboard. What I am wondering is the use in single socket configuration. For example, the following [motherboard](http://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=EP2C602-4L/D16) is a dual socket that support E5-1600/2600/4600. Of course the E5-1600 only support single socket setup.

Comment: It *might* physically work but Serverfault is for professional sysadmins and we inherently only work with supported configurations, anything else isn't considered professional sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  That motherboard requires the [E5-2600 or E5-2600 v2 series CPUs](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/1027/SYS-1027TR-TF.cfm), but it does support using a single CPU, leaving one socket in each node empty (I haven't ever seen a dual socket configuration that didn't work with only one CPU, but they might exist).  You can see on the [SuperMicro Quick Reference](http://www.supermicro.com/QuickRefs/superserver/1U/QRG-1414.pdf) that it specifically lists a single CPU configuration.

Comment: Is this unique to supermicro? Do you know what will happen if I try putting E5-1600 on it? [Other brand](http://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=EP2C602-4L/D16) seems to support it.

Comment: None of the docs mention such a configuration.  I suspect it would work, but isn't supported, so I don't think any professional would recommend it.  There are $200 E5-2600s.  Why would you want to use an E5-1600?

Comment: Our application requires many CPUs with high clock speed (latency sensitive). The E5-1600 and E5-2600 have vastly different prices. Xeon E5-1650 v2, 6 cores, 3.5 Ghz, 12 MB cache is $583. Xeon E5-2643 v2, 6 cores, 3.5 Ghz, 25 MB cache is $1552.

Comment: The upper end of the prices vary somewhat dramatically ($1700 vs $2600), but the low end is the same ($198). See [http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors).  You may have a hard time getting many of those CPUs from your usual retailer, but they do exist.  I see your point with latency, but clock speed is not the only factor for latency, and sometimes you have to pay extra when you're requiring something few others do.